# How to make titleView remain in UINavigationBar during push/pop transition like Facebook app?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, user-interface, uikit

Here is a transitioning animation of `UINavigationBar` used in Facebook for iOS:

[image: Facebook for iOS Navigation Bar Transition Animation]

The `topViewController` is being changed, but the `titleView` is transitioning seamlessly.

(For your information, the two textfields are the same instance (checked with [FLEX](https://github.com/Flipboard/FLEX)). However, I don’t care if the two textfields are not the same instance.)

What's the best way of approaching this?

Thanking you in anticipation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly confident that is not a navigation push/pop.  I suspect what they're doing is hiding the left bar button to make the search field larger, and then just adding a view on top of the current VC's view.  When you cancel, they hide the view and show the bar button.  The clues I'm using to draw this conclusion are that (a) I've been writing iphone apps for years and I have no idea how to make a nav controller/bar do what you want with a push/pop, at least not without a lot of faking it and hoop jumping, (b) you video has the new view "pushing" from the wrong side, and (c) in my copy of the FB app, there is a different animation where the second view just appears/disappears without any push/pop animation.